# Stacked distribution graph (possibly in python)

Tags: python, graph, charts

I would like to draw graphs like this (Sorry, I was not able to upload the picture)
http://www.organizationview.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Stacked-distribution.jpg

Which software can do this? Is there any python utilities that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you a working matplotlib example. I only made three components per bar-chart. Adding two more for the five total in your example is left as an exercise to the reader. :) The code is quoted down below. You can also see it live or download my IPython notebook: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5852773

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

width=0.5

strong_dis = np.array((20, 10, 5, 10, 15))
disagree = np.array((20, 25, 15, 15, 10))
# shortcut here
therest = np.subtract(100, strong_dis + disagree)

q = np.arange(5)

bsd=plt.barh(q, strong_dis, width, color='red')
bd=plt.barh(q, disagree, width, left=strong_dis, color='pink')
br=plt.barh(q, therest, width, left=strong_dis+disagree, color='lightblue')

ylabels = tuple(reversed(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']))
plt.yticks(q+width/2., ylabels)

plt.xlabel('Responses (%)')
plt.legend((bsd, bd, br), ('strong disagree', 'disagree', 'the rest'))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I cannot run this program even after I install numpy and matplotlib. It complains about xlabel and legend not defined. So I use pli.xlabel and pli.legend. Then the program exit normally, but nothing is generated...

Comment: Please try again. I was running IPython in pylab mode (`ipython notebook --pylab=inline`) which means it auto-imports things from pyplot and numpy. I've now fixed the code, it should work in your environment. Also, I've added the explicit plt.show() at the end which is required if you're not in inline mode. This is why you didn't see any plot.

Answer (score 0):

The matplotlib library can be used for generating graphs in Python.
http://matplotlib.org/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/). They have an [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html) section, which includes a [stacked bar chart](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html).